# Is it possible to export angular ui-grid to pdf file?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-grid

I am using the angular `ui-grid` in my `ionic` application and now I want to export the `grid` to a pdf file is it possible to do this using the `ui-grid`?

Comment: Did you check the `ui-grid` documentation here : http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/206_exporting_data ?

Answer (score 0):

Add the directive "ui-grid-exporter" to enable the export options for ui-grid.